# Android Studio Grid Layout seems right in the design and after running looks wrong

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

When I work on Android Studio the grid view look awsome and when I run it in emulator the grid view looks corrupted.

Can anyone help me to get this solved?

---

This is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"/>




    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Design View Image

[image]

This is the Emulator View Image

[image]

Comment: The emulator showing exactly right not a problem with that. Try with other emulator.

Comment: thant you for replying but it was the api problem because the emulator run on api 15 which is not support layout_rowWeight and layout_columnWeight